# mvcPaging documentation - Mvc pagination advice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I am trying to use the MVCPaging for asp.net mvc 3, which can be found [here](http://nuget.org/packages/mvcpaging) but I cannot make it works. I follow this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/07/06/using-mvcpaging-in-asp-net-mvc-apps.aspx) step by step, but when I click on the link pages, which supposed to load into a div as ajax, it opens me another new pages,

My code from the view is:

```
@Html.Pager(1, 1, 2, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "gridcontainer"}).Options(o => o.Action("AjaxPage"))
```

Which calls the action ok, it returns a partial, but the partial page is open into another new page instead of refreshing a div on my actual page

This problem gets me crazy, does any one using this nuget package and knows where the problem may be coming from ?

Otherwise, can you advice me a link / tutorial for asp.net mvc 3 for ajax paging ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and adding a reference to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in your _Layout.cshtml view solved it for me.